# Serialize into a key-value dictionary with Json.Net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Hello I'm trying to serialize an object into a hash, but I'm not getting quite what I want.

Code:

```
class Data{
  public string Name;
  public string Value;
}
//...
var l=new List<Data>();
l.Add(new Data(){Name="foo",Value="bar"});
l.Add(new Data(){Name="biz",Value="baz"});
string json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l);
```

when I do this the `json` result value is

```
[{"Name":"foo","Value":"bar"},{"Name":"biz","Value":"baz"}]
```

The result I want however is this:

```
[{"foo":"bar"},{"biz":"baz"}]
```

How do I made the JSON come out like that?

Comment: @woohoo so you're saying it's not valid JSON? Is there anyway to make it valid while keeping that general structure?

Comment: Well, I personally think that what you want is incorrect, on json.org, see this example: http://www.json.org/example.html

Comment: The format that you need can only be achieved if you write a separate class for "foo" and another one for "baz"... then generalize a little bit more the List<> class, etc. But, you're going against the grain...

Comment: I never tried this - but did you try to put your data on a Dictionary<> and then try to serialize that into json?

Comment: @woohoo - You should actually post an answer so it can be accepted, as your suggestion is what Earlz used.

Answer (score 8):

Try this for the last line of your method:

`string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l.ToDictionary(x=>x.Name, y=>y.Value));`

Result: `{"foo":"bar", "biz":"baz"}`

For result: `[{"foo":"bar"},{"biz":"baz"}]` you can do this...

`string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new object[]{new {foo="bar"}, new {biz = "baz"} });`

OR

`string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new object[]{new Data1{foo="bar"}, new Data2{biz = "baz"} });`

The first result assumes same data type, so results are part of same array. The second is different data types, so you get a different array

Comment: This works! I ended up not using a `Data` class though and instead just serialized a `Dictionary<string,string>`

Comment: or wait. actually that doesn't.

Comment: @Earlz, just added different way to get expected output.

Comment: is there some way to do this dynamically?

Comment: Depends on your actual needs. Can you just serialize an object that matches your need? Do you have to create the json from strings? Yes, its possible, but implementation depends on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own key value list
like

```
 class mylist:Dictionary<string,object>
{
}
var l=new mylist<Data>();
l.Add("foo","bar");
```

it should solve your problem