# Make web api serialize dictionary with the key value as key using data attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, json.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a dictionary which I am serializing using the json.net serializer, and it is currently producing

```
{"phrases":[{"Key":"my-key1","Value":"blah"},{"Key":"my-key2","Value":"blah2"}]}
```

however I want it to output

```
{"phrases":["my-key1":"blah"},{"my-key2":"blah2"}]}
```

my model looks like

```
public class Phrases
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> phrases;
}
```

Is there a data attribute I can apply to the phrases model to cause this to happen?

I found the following but don't want to be returning a string [Serialize into a key-value dictionary with Json.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862177/serialize-into-a-key-value-dictionary-with-json-net)

UPDATE:

I am extending the web api controller as follows, if I use JsonConvert.SerializeObject() I do get the correct serialization , however I would then have a string to return.

```
public class PhraseController : ApiController
    {
        private IApplicationModel applicationModel;

        public Phrases Get(string id)
        {
            var locale = new CultureInfo(id).LCID;
            var phrases = applicationModel.Phrases.Where(x => x.Locale = locale).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, y => y.Value);

            return new Phrases() { phrases = phrases };
        }

        public PhraseController(IApplicationModel applicationModel)
        {
            this.applicationModel = applicationModel;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which json.net version do you use? Because the `"Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.0.8"` produces this: `{"phrases":{"my-key1":"blah","my-key2":"blah2"}}` using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(phrases);`

Comment: @nemesv have updated my question

Comment: Am wondering if my problem is that it is still using the DataContractJsonSerializer instead of json.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it to work in the end.

Problem was that it was still using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`. I added a line removing the formatters before adding the `JsonNetFormatter` and it now serializes correctly.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonNetFormatter(null));
```

(I am using the beta release which still uses the DataContractJsonSerializer)